# Selenium chrome not loading images for specific website

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium with chromium-browser on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS rented from Linode. It loads images for all other websites but doesn't load for a specific website(it was loading before but then stopped). I tried on another Linode Ubuntu 20.04 LTS but also doesn't load there. If I try with ubuntu 20.04 LTS on my virtual machine, it loads images. It also loads images with Chrome on Windows.

If I try with firefox on Ubuntu, it loads images. But I want it to work with chromium-browser.

I have tried with different proxies and user agents.

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from selenium import webdriver

from sys import platform
from time import sleep

browser = 'chrome'
headless = True

if platform == 'win32':
    if browser == 'chrome':
        PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe'
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        PATH = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\geckodriver.exe'
else:    
    if browser == 'chrome':
        PATH = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        PATH = '/usr/bin/geckodriver'


def init_driver(proxy):
    ua = UserAgent()
    user_agent = ua.random
    
    if browser == 'chrome':    
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')        
        if headless:
            options.add_argument('--headless')         
        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')    
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)    
    elif browser == 'firefox':
        options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
        options.add_argument(f'--proxy-server={proxy}')        
        if headless:
            options.add_argument('--headless')         
        options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')    
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=PATH, options=options) 
    else:
        print('invalid browser')
    return driver
        
proxy = ''        
driver = init_driver(proxy)
driver.get('')
driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
driver.quit()
```

Comment: You can use the firefox webdriver, if the images are loading there? Run all your tests in firefox webdriver. Can you please tell which specific website you are using?

Comment: Probably your site is not completely loaded. Try adding waits before taking a screenshot.

Comment: @SwaroopHumane I am running multiple tests in parallel. The problem with firefox is it runs fine for some time and then starts to give error (Message: connection refused using geckodriver and firefox). The website is https://reformaprocesal.pjud.cl/ConsultaCausasJsfWeb/page/panelConsultaCausas.jsf

Comment: @vitaliis I tried adding wait. Still doesn't load images.